# Printwrite always overwriting file

Tags: java, arrays, printwriter

im trying to match phone numbers so i could print them to a .txt file but im having a bit of trouble.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Fixed your title. It stated exactly the reverse of the case. NB You wouldn't seriously open and close a file for every line of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use append mode:

```
FileWriter output = new FileWriter("result.txt", true);
PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(output));
```